# KSH remove digits from number precision

Tags: ksh, precision, digits

I am trying to compare 2 log files in a ksh script that look like

log1:

```
10100 951 5 20150318 20150430 
10101 11950 0 20150323 20150630 
10102 285933 1 20150128 20150430 
10041 57007 3.53 20150128 20150430
```

log2

```
10100 951 5.0000 20150318 20150430
10101 11950 0.0000 20150323 20150630
10102 285933 1.0000 20150128 20150430
10041 57007 3.5300 20150128 20150430
```

`Log1` on `column 3` has maximum 2 digits after the **`.`** (eg: 3.53)

`Log2` on `colum 3` always has 4 digits after the **`.`** (eg: 0.0000 or 3.5300)

How could I add some digits after . for the first log or remove the digits in log2 in order to be able to compare them line for line?

My script is written in `ksh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should format the value with printf:

```
cat log1 | while read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5; do
   printf "%d %d %.4f %d %d\n" ${col1} ${col2} ${col3} ${col4} ${col5}
done > log1.converted
```

Above code reads easy, but makes an unnecessary call to cat ("UUOC").
The better way to write this is

```
while read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5; do
    printf "%d %d %.4f %d %d\n" ${col1} ${col2} ${col3} ${col4} ${col5}
done < log1 > log1.converted
```